# decode_json and return first key in hash

Tags: json, perl

JSON string input: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo

I am trying to return just the first key (current day) in the hash but have been unable to do so. My code looks like the following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $html = get("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=AMD&apikey=CMDPTEHVYH7W5VSZ");

my $decoded = decode_json($html);
my ($open) = $decoded->{'Time Series (Daily)'}->[0]->{'1. open'};
```

I keep getting "Not an ARRAY reference" which I researched and got more confused.

I can access what I want directly with the below code but I want to access just the first result or the current day:

```
my ($open) = $decoded->{'Time Series (Daily)'}{'2017-12-20'}{'1. open'};
```

Also if I do something like this:

```
my ($open) = $decoded->{'Time Series (Daily)'};
print Dumper($open);
```

The output is as follows:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '2017-09-07' => {
                        '1. open' => '12.8400',
                        '5. volume' => '35467788',
                        '2. high' => '12.9400',
                        '4. close' => '12.6300',
                        '3. low' => '12.6000'
                      },
      '2017-11-15' => {
                        '3. low' => '10.7700',
                        '4. close' => '11.0700',
                        '2. high' => '11.1300',
                        '5. volume' => '33326871',
                        '1. open' => '11.0100'
                      },
      '2017-11-30' => {
                        '1. open' => '10.8700',
                        '2. high' => '11.0300',
                        '5. volume' => '43101899',
                        '3. low' => '10.7600',
                        '4. close' => '10.8900'
                      },
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide a noob.

Comment: hashes are not ordered, so they don't have "first key"s and you can't do `->[0]` on them.  you will have to figure out which key you want, perhaps by finding the minimum string?

Answer (score 4):

You are picking among hashref keys, not array (sequential container) elements. Since hashes are inherently unordered you can't index into that list but need to sort keys as needed.

With the exact format you show this works

```
my $top = (sort { $b cmp $a } keys %{ $decoded->{'Time Series (Daily)'} } )[0];
say $decoded->{'Time Series (Daily)'}{$top}{'1. open'};
```

It gets the list of keys, inverse-sorts them (alphabetically), and takes the first element of that list.

If your date-time format may vary then you'll need to parse it for sorting.

If you will really ever only want the most-recent one this is inefficient since it sorts the whole list.  Then use a more specific tool to extract only the "largest" element, like

```
use List::Util qw(reduce);

my $top = reduce { $a gt $b ? $a : $b } 
          keys %{ $decoded->{'Time Series (Daily)'} };
```

But then in your case this can be done simply by `maxstr` from the same [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) module, as shown in ikegami's answer. On the other hand, if the datetime format doesn't lend itself to a direct lexicographical comparison used by `strmax` then the `reduce` allows use of custom comparisons.

Answer (score 4):

Problem 1: `{` denotes the start of a JSON object, which gets decoded into a hash. Trying to derefence an array is going to fail.

Problem 2: Like Perl hashes, JSON objects are unordered, so talking about the 
"first key" makes no sense. Perhaps you want the most recent date?

```
use List::Util qw( maxstr );

my $time_series_daily = $decoded->{'Time Series (Daily)'};
my $latest_date = maxstr @$time_series_daily;
my $open = $time_series_daily->{$latest_date}{'1. open'};
```